# Combinatorics: Stirling first kind identity

Tags: combinatorics

Claim:
$\sum\limits_{m=k}^{n}s(n,m){m\choose k}=s(n+1,k+1)$
My attempt at a proof is the following:

I wanted to use induction and a particular recursive identity we have for these beasts -

$s(n+1,k+1)=s(n−1,k−1)+(n−1)s(n−1,k)$
So the base case n=0 would be straightforward, but assuming n --

We could write the RHS as:
$s(n+1,k+1)=s(n−1,k−1)+(n−1)s(n−1,k)$
In this case we'd be able to apply our induction hypothesis to s(n−1,k−1) and get a summation, but I'm not sure how to work with the right hand side in this case, or if this is even the right way to think about this problem. Ideally, someone that has some combinatorial intuition for this could give me a story-type way of looking at this - but any and all help is appreciated. Thanks so much.